# localStorage returns NULL

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I've stumpled into a problem regarding localStorage. My code looks like this:

```
var defaultReportData = {
  'station': 'DR P3',
  'days': 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri',
  'startHour': '06:00',
  'endHour': '18:00',
  'demography': 'Cover: All'
}

localStorage.setItem('defaultReportData', JSON.stringify(defaultReportData));

// Returns null
console.log(localStorage.getItem('station'));
```

Whenever I just type out "localStorage" in my console after loading the page, the object gets output correctly. However, the localStorage output returns null in my console when I want to get a specific value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defaultReportData')).station);

Comment: You are using a different storage name for retrieving than setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1049/)**.

You've to parse the returned string to JSON to get the `station` like :

```
var defaultReportData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defaultReportData'));
console.log( defaultReportData.station );
```

Comment: I think better explanation of problem is to **use the same key used at the time of storage**

Answer (score 2):

You have to **retrieve** data from localStorage using the same **`key`**(defaultReportData) used at the time of storage and then parse the string data to JSON Object

```
var data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('defaultReportData'));
console.log(data.station);
```

Answer (score 1):

> It works, just copy and paste to your console

```js
    var defaultReportData = {
      'station': 'DR P3',
      'days': 'Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri',
      'startHour': '06:00',
      'endHour': '18:00',
      'demography': 'Cover: All'
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('defaultReportData', JSON.stringify(defaultReportData));

    // Returns null

    var itemPref = window.localStorage.getItem('defaultReportData')

    var resultObject = JSON.parse(itemPref);

    console.log(resultObject.station);
```